# How can I match the radius of the curve to the point's scale when the points are moving?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image: Preview]
[image: Geometry node]
As you can see, when the points aren't moving, the radius of the control point matches the scale of points, but when points are moving, the position of scale is offset, How can I match the radius of the curve to the point's scale when the points are moving?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the points to use the radius of their current locations, just sample the curve radius at the position and set the point radius to the value.

[image: node tree]

[image: result]

---

But if you want the change of radius between frames to be applied to the points: Using a Simulation Zone, add to the point radius the curve's radius difference between the current and previous frame.

[image: node tree]

[image: result]

[image]$\small\color{DarkOrange}{|}\hspace{2pt}\color{gray}{{\tiny\text{V}}\text{3.6.5}}\hspace{2pt}\color{DarkOrange}{|}$

Comment: Thanks bro, you are my hero!